# Android altbeacon sensibility and new beacons

Tags: android, beacon, altbeacon

I've seen a lot of discussions on battery for altbeacon, specially if beacons are inside a region for a long time. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38836830/does-the-advertisement-rate-of-a-beacon-affect-battery-of-a-detector-application) post was actually very clarifying.

I am currently working in a solution that requires a good sensibility (which I define as being a small detection time for a new beacon in a region).

As some beacons may be anonymous (which I define as presenting unexpected MAC addresses but share a same matching byte sequence) to the scanner in this particular solution, I would like to achieve good sensibility to new beacons but also a balanced battery impact to the user.

What concerns me is if a first beacon is found and the region triggers based on the matching sequence, how could I get a notification once another beacon approaches (or leaves) ?

A guess I was going to try was to keep monitoring for a generic matching sequence and once a beacon is found for that general sequence, range it to get its address and them create a particular region for the mac I've taken. The only problem with this approach was how could I prevent the first beacon to keep triggering the generic region?

And just out of curiosity. Is the ScanFilter class related to those hardware filters introduced on android 5?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

If you need to quickly  find *new* beacons with the same byte patterns as ones that already exist in the vicinity, you really have no choice but to keep ranging.

In such a situation, there is no distinction between ranging and monitoring in terms of battery consumption.  Both will require constant Bluetooth scans and decoding of all beacons in the vicinity.  Scan filters (yes, the hardware filters introduced in Android 5,) will not help because you expect the byte patterns to be the same.  There is no such thing as a packet "does not match" scan filter that could be used to find only new MAC addresses.

You may need to accept the battery drain of constant scans and just try to limit how long they last, if your use case allows.  Short scans of 30 minutes or less might be acceptable.

You could possibly save some battery by writing your own BLE scanning parsing code tailored to this use case.  You could first look for unique MAC addresses, and only do further processing and parsing if the MAC address has never been seen before.  This will not reduce battery usage from the constant scan, but it would cut down on battery usage from CPU expended on  parsing packets.  This might save 10-30% depending on the number of beacons in the vicinity.

Bottom line: you are right to be concerned about battery usage with this use case.

Comment: If I theorically could modify the beacon advertising byte sequence to provide a good variation of byte sequences (eg. 255) and keep ranging slow, would I take advantage from android LE low power scan, considering region 'collisions' are mitigated?

Comment: Saving significant power with low power scans really relies on a small number of ScanFilters.  You need to figure out a way to have only one or two ScanFilters active at any given time for this to work, because offloading the filters to the Bluetooth chip are critical to power savings.  The number of hardware filter slots is specific to the Bluetooth chip,  but I do not believe any chips support 255.  The whole system is really designed to find one byte pattern.